# How to read set-cookie header from http post on Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient

I'm trying to authenticate in a website but I can't read the Cookie from the response of my request.

I'm using Ionic 3 with a proxy to bypass CORS (adding it to ionic.config.json).

I'm using HttpClient from angular to make the request.

```
this.httpClient.post("/user.php", formData, {responseType: "text", withCredentials: true}).subscribe((login)=>{
  this.httpClient.post("/user.php?method=getUserData&input=3", {}, { withCredentials: true}).subscribe((userData)=>{
});
```

I'm using withCredentials: true and the second request doesn't use the cookie that the first request generates.

Is there any way to use that cookie?

Thank you in advanced.

**Edit:** Without proxy and with the real url in an Android / iOS device it works fine.

Is there a way to fix that with Ionic Proxy?